# How to increase margin spacing utility from 3rem to even more in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am completely new to Bootstrap and right now I am converting a free PSD to a webpage using Bootstrap 4.

In the PSD the top-margin space between the navigation bar and slogan section is quite big around 150px.

To apply margin space using Bootstrap I was using spacing utility class "mt-xl-*". As explained in the documentation we can go only upto 3rem. But that is not enough according to the design.

So I want to increase the rem value from '3' to even more, so can I do it? Would I need to make modifications using Saas or should I go the old standard CSS way of applying margin directly?

```css
header{
 background-image: url('images/background-images/header-background.jpg');
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: top;
}

.nav-item{
 color: #ffffff;
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 font-size: 18px;
 text-decoration: none;
}

#slogan-block p{
 text-align: center;
}

#slogan-block p:first-child{
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-size: 45px;
 font-weight: 600;
}

#slogan-block p:nth-child(2){
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-size: 16px;
}

div.header-controls button{
 width: 100%;
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 300;
 font-size: 18px;
 height: 50px;
 border-radius: 25px;
}

#ask-for-price-control button{
 background-color: #ffffff;
 color: #d32721;
 border: 0;
}

#watch-video-control button{
 background-color: transparent;
 color: #ffffff;
 border: 1px solid #ffffff;
}

.mt-xl-6{
 margin-top: ($spacer * 6) !important;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="master.css">
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="fluid-container">
  
  <div class="container">
   <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
     <img src="images/logo/logo.png">
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
     <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
     <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link" href="#">Our Drones</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link" href="#">Our Realizations</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </nav>
   
   <div class="row">
    <div id="slogan-block" class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 mt-xl-6">
     <p>Film your event with us!</p>
     <p>Pellentesque eget nunc sit amet urna ullamcorper fermentum et eu leo.<br>Nunc vel nibh tempor, pharetra lectus congue, luctus orci.</p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row justify-content-center mt-xl-5">
    <div id="ask-for-price-control" class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-2 header-controls">
     <button>Ask For Price</button>
    </div>
    <div id="watch-video-control" class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-2 header-controls">
     <button>Watch Video</button>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  
 </header>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: This is the design which I am trying to develop using Bootstrap 4]

Comment: Are you able to use SASS?

Comment: I am sorry but I don't know Sass!

Answer (score 3):

You can increase all the spacing helper classes. The best way is to customize source code.

#### Default spacing which is defined inside `__variables.scss`

```css
$spacer: 1rem !default;
$spacers: () !default;
$spacers: map-merge((
        0: 0,
        1: ($spacer * .25),
        2: ($spacer * .5),
        3: $spacer,
        4: ($spacer * 1.5),
        5: ($spacer * 3)
), $spacers);
```

To add new properties, just add new `key:value` in the same way as the other six properties.

```css
$spacer: 1rem !default;
$spacers: () !default;
$spacers: map-merge((
        6: ($spacer * 4),
        7: ($spacer * 5)
), $spacers);
```

Dosing so, you can use all the variants of `*-6-*` and `*-6-*` classes, for example, `mt-6` and `pt-6`.

Comment: Okay, I got that, but don't you think it will be irrelevant to modify or add new Saas variables for a simple job?

No offense! And no intention to hurt someones feeling! But in my personal opinion I believe that it would be good to just use a custom css property to resolve this issue rather than manipulating with Saas. 

This is just a general thought of mine.

Comment: Generally, it is good to do so, because you may need in the future.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your help friend.

Comment: Read your question again. I guess you have forgotten what you have asked?

Comment: Yes, I understood what you meant. I asked how to increase the spacing utility value? And as expected I got an answer to use Sass.